# Beamercolorbox has no color

Tags: beamer

I'm using the `Warsaw` beamer theme and try to customize it because the section headline is way too big for my presentation (about 7 sections). I found a way to display only the section names in the headline. 
It looks pretty much like I want it to except the headline is not colored. The highlighting of the sections works but the colors won't. I'm not quite sure what the problem is. I use a `beamercolorbox` but it's just white. In the footline the exact same code produces a colored box.

The code I use for the headline:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=5ex,dp=3.5ex]{sec}%
    \raggedright%
    \hspace*{2em}%
    {\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{0.7\textwidth}{}{}}%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
```

[image]

I'd really appreciate your help,

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) No need to add thanks, simply upvote any good answers you may receive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to setup the color used for the headline template

```
\setbeamercolor{headline}{fg=yellow,bg=red}
```

should draw your box with a red background and a yellow text.

Comment: Your answer works, but the problem still exists. The thing is the name of the beamercolorbox. It turns out you can't give it any name you want. (Old habit from programming) But your answer brought me to the solution.

Comment: BTW, you won a lottery "Make a Post Number 100000 on TeX.SX" :)

Comment: @Prometheus I don't really understand what you mean. In beamer, there are a number of named templates that do some defined job; headline is one of them. So you can't rename it "myheadline" without providing all the necessary code.